# Prevent script from generating stdout if called from given program

Tags: shell-script, ssh, stdout

I want my gnome-terminal to show my current user and host in its titlebar, and that of the remote when I am using ssh.

To do that, I created a script `~/bin/ssh`, with `~/bin` in my `PATH` before `/usr/bin`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -ne "\033]0;${1}\007"
/usr/bin/ssh $@
```

This works fine (arguably, not robust for unexpected argument order). Even after exiting the ssh session, the window title recovers nicely.

My problem is that other programs that try to use `ssh` are disturbed by the `stdout` this generates. `git fetch` for example, barfs on `\033]0;`.

My question is: how can I better the script so that it keeps its name `ssh`, but gives `stdout` only in relevant cases?

There must be some kind of variable to tell if there is any window title to change? I guess `TERM` is still defined when running via `git`, so that wouldn't work.

Can I send the string to another stream?

Should I parse the `ssh` options and not output to `stdout` in certain conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want your script  to check if its stdout is going to a tty or not.

Referring to this stackoverflow question, [check isatty in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10022323/7552)

```
#!/bin/bash

# set the terminal title, if I'm running in a terminal
if [[ -t 1 ]]; then echo -ne "\033]0;${1}\007"; fi

/usr/bin/ssh "$@"
```

Note that you always want to quote `"$@"`